# Awk not working inside bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

Im trying to write a bash script and trying to take input from user and executing a kill command to stop a specific tomcat.

...

```
read user_input
if [ "$user_input" = "2" ]
then
ps -ef | grep "search-tomcat" |awk {'"'"'print $2'"'"'}| xargs kill -9
echo "Search Tomcat Shut Down"
fi
```

...

I have confirmed that the line

> ps -ef | grep "search-tomcat"

works fine in script but:

> ps -ef | grep "search-tomcat" |awk {'"'"'print $2'"'"'}

doesnt yield any results in script, but gives desired output in terminal, so there has to be some problem with awk command

Comment: you can try `awk '{print "\047" $2 "\047"}'` ?

Comment: That seems to work! But now Im stuck at the last part: passing the results as a parameters to xargs.

Comment: @BhuvanRawal: Do you have `pkill` command available?

Comment: ok, only to remember `"` (quotes) is `"\042"` and `'` (apostrophe)  is `"\047"`

Comment: Thanks Jose! 

@anubhava: Ya I have `pkill` command available.

Comment: Then you just need `pkill -9 -f "search-tomcat"`

Comment: use the `{}` tool in the edit box menu at the top left on highlighted text get get properly formatted code, data, output and error msgs ;-) Good luck!

Comment: Are the backticks around your code literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xargs can be tricky - Try:

> **kill -9 $(ps -ef | awk '/search-tomcat/ {print $2}')**

If you prefer using xargs then check man page for options for your target OS (i.e. xargs -n.)

Also noting that 'kill -9' is a non-graceful process exit mechanism (i.e. possible file corruption, other strangeness) so I suggest only using as a last resort...

:)

Comment: Thanks for your views @Dale_Reagan. The command works brilliantly.

I understand that its not a great idea to use `kill -9` , but Ive seen that tomcats doesnt stop via regular `catalina.sh stop` any insight on this?

Comment: Sorry, no real experience w/Tomcat, but understand that sometimes kill -9 is needed.  Watch out for the zombies! :)

Comment: Zombies can be painful. But somehow kill almost always works fine in my case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dale.